# Concat three list by entry

Tags: c#

I was just wondering whether it is posisble to concat list by entry so;

```
 List One  Concat   List Two  Concat    List Three
Entry One   ->      Entry Two  ->       Entry Three 
Entry One   ->      Entry Two  ->       Entry Three 
Entry One   ->      Entry Two  ->       Entry Three
```

The reason I ask is I have three list that loop the values  I need off diferent parts of the program. I need a way on concat the entries in the order they appear across the three list. The code for looping each list is;

```
List<string> QualificationList = new List<string>();
            List<string> SubjectList = new List<string>();
            List<string> GradeList = new List<string>();

            foreach (XmlNode QualificationNode in GetQualification)
            {
                GetQualificationType = QualificationNode.InnerText;
                QualificationList.Add(GetQualificationType);
            }

            foreach (XmlNode SubjectNode in GetSubject)
            {
                GetSubjects = SubjectNode.InnerText;
                SubjectList.Add(GetSubjects);
            }

            foreach (XmlNode node in GetGrade)
            {
                GetGrades = node.InnerText;
                GradeList.Add(GetGrades);
            }
```

I was just wondering whether this is possible if not how could I gather the information which I need to concat or stringbuilder properly. Thanks for any help which you can provide

Comment: What are you trying to do with them? are they the same length? if they are just use a for loop and all three lists each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `Zip`:

```
var concatList = QualificationList.Zip(SubjectList, (q,s) => new {q, s})
                                  .Zip(GradeList, (qs, g) => new {qs.q, qs.s, qs.g})
```

That will give you an anonymous type with three properties: `q` (qualification), `s` (subject), and `g` (grade).  If you want to concatenate them into one string just project it with `Select`:

```
                                  .Select( qsg => string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", q, s, g);
```

You could also replace each `xxxList` with a projection if you want; it just adds more complexity to the Linq statement (and may make it harder to debug):

```
var concatList = GetQualification.Select(node => node.InnerText)
                                 .Zip(GetSubject.Select(node => node.InnerText),
                                      (q,s) => new {q, s})
                                 .Zip(GetGrade.Select(node => node.InnerText),
                                      (qs, g) => new {qs.q, qs.s, qs.g})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified to this:

```
QualificationList.AddRange(GetQualification.Select(item => item.InnerText));
SubjectList.AddRange(GetSubject.Select(item => item.InnerText));
GradeList.AddRange(GetGrade.Select(item => item.InnerText));
```

Using [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) will save you from the loops and [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) method will return the texts inside the order they appear.

Comment: In this case the expanded code is visually more appealing... Also through personal trials of large datasets a `foreach` loop is generally faster